# Gráficos 3D python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tenho 3 arrays, a partir dos arrays devo desenhar um gráfico 3D. Já tentei de várias formas mas não consegui. Creio que não estou criando os *data frames* corretamente. Estou tentando fazer desta forma:

```
x = np.array(x_values)
y = np.array(y_values)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.array(z_values)

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='viridis',edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

O código está retornando o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

Comment: O argumento Z deve ter duas dimensões e no caso que você colocou o seu Z só tem uma dimensão. Dá uma olha da no exemplo neste site: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html

Answer (score -2):

`Z` tem que ser uma função que dependa de X e Y. Ex: `np.sin(x)*np.sin(y)`